# SP13 - How to delete created Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, page-layout

I create Page Layout from **Design Manager Section**. I want to delete this Layout. How to do this.

This is my **prntScreen**:

[image]

Comment: Are you using page-layouts in SharePoint Foundation?

Comment: Did you manage to delete the page layout?

Comment: I've just created as I associate it with certain content without publish it and use it somewhere ...

Comment: Don't worry as if you did not published it than it will no create any problem after deleting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to the **Master Page gallery** of your site. As in SharePoint 2013 by default, for each Page Layout, two files – .aspx and html are Created (Like below for your reference).

[image]

So you need to find out the proper files & **delete them both**.

Comment: I find this files, next i select files and click on Files(delete document)?

Comment: Yes but make sure that you are not using them in any of the page created in your environment otherwise it will break all the pages. I suggest you to download those files first & delete them.

Comment: In future, If any page uses those page layouts than you can upload them again & publish it so pages which are using it will work fine for you.

Comment: Is that works for you?

Comment: I only create this page layout.. I do not use anywhere and not publish it..

Comment: Last from where i delete my page layout, please edit your question to approve..

Comment: & upvote my answer to help me as well

Comment: If you need more help than please let me know